# WP (BeTheme) sticky header appearance

Tags: wordpress, sticky

Is it possible to change where the sticky-header appears?

I am using WP with BeTheme. I want to change the value of pixels scrolled so that you have to scroll a bit more down to make it appear.

[image]

Here you can see that I ticked the sticky header option. I could have done this as well with `position:fixed` but that's the easy way.

[image]

Here you can see my top_bar and the scroll position on value 0 (I guess).

[image]

well... and here you can see that after a few pixels scrolled, the top_bar disappears and the sticky header shows up.

I think my sketch explains well what I want to achieve.

If you need more information just ask!

Thanks for your help^^